# Unable to reach localhost:3000/

Tags: node.js, ssl, browser, localhost, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a react application and for testing some services I wrote a node server in my notebook. It seems that from the app and from the browser I cannot point to https://localhost:3000 due to `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

I just tried doing some actions like reset all SSL certificates, trying different browser but the only result I found it's that I can reach my server from the browser but not via react.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to install https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app and see if the sample app run on localhost

Comment: @fedeteka Done and working but I need to point in some services in http and not in https

Comment: OK, not specified on the original question "I cannot point to https://localhost:3000"

Answer (score 1):

Try http://localhost:3000

Just validated with one of my projects to make sure

The dev server doesn't support https

Comment: Yes I just tried on https and working but for now I need to test some services served on http

Answer (score 1):

The localhost:3000 should be hit by: "http://localhost:3000"

If that is not working then the port number can be changed.

In REACT, the port number can be changed with:

"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"

Comment: Thanks but actually I'm not using a script for start but MAKE DEV

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the app? Maybe with

```
set HTTPS=false&&npm start
```